# Memory issue decodeObjectForKey (Swift project)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory, crash

Within an Swift application exporting the individual single viewController images (using the drawViewHierarchyInRect).

For each viewController I recover the contents of imageViews as follows:

```
self.imageView = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("imageLevel") as? UIImageView)
self.imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
self.imageView!.multipleTouchEnabled = true
self.imageView!.autoresizesSubviews = true
self.addSubview(imageView!)
```

After 15 "page": crash. If I comment these lines, the code works again. Is there an alternative to `decodeObjectForKey`?

Comment: Could you put the crash log here?

Comment: Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're doing here, but you shouldn't be trying to encode a UIImageView and save it off as the view is tied to other items.  You could encode the UIImage instead.  Your UIImageView should come from your storyboard/xib and then you set the image you decoded to the UIImageView.

Comment: In my app the step is following:     

- User create a page (new viewController)   
- User import a image   
- User modify image   
- User save image "encodeObject"  
- User open page and load image by "decodeObject"  
- User create PDF of all page by "drawViewHierarchyInRect" but crash after "x" page